# Как сделать проверку на значение таблицы

Tags: php, laravel

Нужно чтобы шла проверка по всем пользователям в таблице (ban_drivers) по колонке (ban_do) если значение в (ban_do) у какого-то пользователя совпадает с (сегодняшней датой и временем) то совершается указанное действие.

***есть Kernel.php***

```
$schedule->call(function () {
        $s = Carbon::now();
        $ban_all=ban_drivers::all();
        $ban_drivers=ban_drivers::find($ban_all);
        $ban=$ban_drivers->ban_do;
        if($s>=$ban){
            $ban_drivers->delete();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше использовать where для получения списка строк по условию

```
$s = Carbon::now();
$bans = ban_drivers::where('ban_do', '<=', $s)->get();
```

и обработать их в цикле. Если надо просто удалить эти строки, то можно сразу

```
ban_drivers::where('ban_do', '<=', $s)->delete();
```